# Doesn't get success message in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have controller called IndexController.php. I am getting message when i delete record in deleteAction().But i doesn't get any message when i add or edit record in addcategoryAction.Can anyone please look at in my controller and check why i doesn't get any message in addcategoryAction.  Here is my controller.

```
<?php
class Company_Web_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {    
        $this->loadLayout();     
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function addcategoryAction()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) 
        {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $id = $data['editid'];
            $catName = $data['catName'];
            $status = $data['status'];
            $data = array('name'=>$catName,'status'=>$status);
            $model = Mage::getModel('web/web');
            if($id == '')
            {
                $model->setData($data);
                try {
                        $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
                } catch (Exception $e){
                 echo $e->getMessage();
                }
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Category has been successfully Added'));
            }
            else
            {
                $model->load($id)->addData($data);
                try {
                        $model->setId($id)->save();
                } catch (Exception $e){
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Category has been successfully Updated'));
            }
            $this->_redirect('web/index/category');

        }
        $this->loadLayout();     
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function categoryAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        $id =  $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $model = Mage::getModel('web/web');
        $model->setId($id)->delete();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Category has been successfully Deleted'));
        $this->_redirect('web/index/category');
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below code in controller action

```
$this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
  $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session');
```

Before render the layout using below code

```
$this->renderLayout();
```

and your below code in phtml file `<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>`
According to `addcategoryAction`  it is redirecting to `categoryAction` after model save

SO.modifed categoryAction is

```
 public function categoryAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
     $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session');
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

And add <`div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>` in phtml file of  `categoryAction`

Comment: Thanks dude. But why in deleteAction it is working and in addcategoryAction not working. In both Action it is redirecting url on same listing page.

Comment: is addcategory  used for save data  or also addcategory also have a lauyut for showing details

Comment: Now i am able to get message when editing record. But for add it is not working.Can you plaese tell me why this is not working ?

Comment: Dude it is working now for Both add and edit. But it working for customer session only. For core session it is not working.

Comment: Adding messages to the session works best when redirecting afterwards. Adding a session message and then rendering the layout is a bit more tricky. I notice that in addcategoryAction, if it's a post request, you're actually doing both - this could have unpredictable results. I'd recommend putting the loadLayout and renderLayout commands in an `else` block.